# ftp server connection timed out

Tags: filezilla, forwarding, htaccess

I've forwarded a domain from the htaccess file some time ago.
For example, I have www.mywebsite.com and I've forwarded it to www.facebook.com from the htaccess file. 
Now when I try to connect with FileZilla I receive:

Status: Connecting to 64.202.189.170:21...
Error:  Connection timed out
Error:  Could not connect to server

This issue has anything to do with the forwarding on the htaccess file ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

htaccess is a per-directory configuration file that Apache reads, Apache is web-server software using the HTTP protocol. HTTP usually operates on port 80.

FileZilla is (primarily at least) a file-transfer client using the FTP protocol. FTP usually operates on port 21.

You may be confusing things (if not please explain further).

Comment: Absolutely right.

Comment: So if I understand correct the ftp has nothing to do with the htaccess?

Comment: @Alecs: You understand correctly.